Las cadenas de traducción de flutter intl no se actualizan
He rescatado un proyecto antiguo al que tengo que hacer ciertos cambios, uno de ellos es cambiar las cadenas de traducción que están guardadas en los archivos .arb de la carpeta l10n. Sin embargo, resulta que el archivo l10n.dart situado en la carpeta generated, no se actualiza al cambiar el valor de las cadenas de traducción.
Según tengo entendido, debería hacerse automáticamente, al tener en pubspec.yml lo siguiente:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_intl:
  enabled: true

He probado a ejecutar flutter intl: initialize y no ocurre nada, pero tampoco da mensaje de error. Recuerdo que cuando trabajé con este proyecto anteriormente, las cadenas de traducción se modificaban automaticamente al cambiar los archivos .arb, sin embargo ahora no ocurre eso.
EDITO: Resulta que hay que ejecutar flutter gen-l10n para que se actualice el archivo. Pero aún así no se actualiza.
EDITO2: He actualizado el pubspec.yml de esta manera, por si acaso, y tampoco produce resultados:
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
  arb-dir: lib/l10n
  output-dir: lib/generated

